# Could Not Connect to Internet Even After Installing wvdial

Tags: wireless, internet, usb-modem, modem, wvdial

After I start `wvdial`, I get the following lines

```
$sudo wvidal

 WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
    Initializing modem.
    Sending: ATZ
    OK
    Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
    ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
    OK
    Modem initialized.
    Sending: ATDT#777
    Waiting for carrier.
    ATDT#777
    CONNECT 3100000
    Carrier detected.  Waiting for prompt.
    ~[7f]}#@!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$@#}%}&[7f]},H8}'}"}(}"F_~
    PPP negotiation detected.
    Starting pppd at Wed Nov 13 07:16:38 2013
    Pid of pppd: 12638
    Using interface ppp0
    pppd: `�9[08]X�9[08]
    pppd: `�9[08]X�9[08]
    pppd: `�9[08]X�9[08]
    pppd: `�9[08]X�9[08]
    local  IP address 115.242.214.172
    pppd: `�9[08]X�9[08]
    remote IP address 220.224.141.145
    pppd: `�9[08]X�9[08]
    primary   DNS address 220.226.6.104
    pppd: `�9[08]X�9[08]
    secondary DNS address 220.226.100.40
    pppd: `�9[08]X�9[08]
```

This is my `wvdial.conf` file;

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 9600
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
ISDN = 0
Phone = #777
Password = 9382741646
Username = 9382741646
```

Is there any mistake in the config file ?

Should I do any thing after I run `wvdial` in terminal to get the internet to work ?

Comment: Found the answer :-)

Comment: so post it as a answer: May helpful for others.

Comment: @Dumindu ya i tried to post it. But i am not allowed to post it for 8 hours since my reputation is less than 10. Ill post it after 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer and thought to share it with you guys.

`wvdial` needs several other packages to be installed, which can be fetched from the Internet. Since, I can't connect to the Internet without modem, I manually downloaded these required packages.

Download the package files from these links (If you're using 64-bit, choose amd64, otherwise i386):

- `libwvstreams4.6-base` http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libwvstreams4.6-base
- `libwvstreams4.6-extras` http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libwvstreams4.6-extras
- `libuniconf4.6` http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libuniconf4.6
- `wvdial` http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/wvdial

Save them in your home folder. Then install them all using this command

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Then edit `/etc/wvdial.conf` using `sudo -i gedit /etc/wvdial.conf` with the following configurations.

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = USB Modem
CBaud = 460800
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
ISDN = 0
Phone = #777
Stupid Mode = 1
Password = password-provided-by-your-isp
Username = username-provided-by-your-isp
```

the `Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0` value may be `/dev/ttyUSB2` based on which port your device is attached to.